# Appears in the NgModule.imports of ExtendedSearchModule, but itself has errors?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Everywhere in modules I get this error message:

> Appears in the NgModule.imports of Module, but itself has errors.

Before it was working fine.

[image]

My tsconfig is:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
        "lib": ["es2019", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"]
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
        "strictInjectionParameters": true
    }
}
```

What can be wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: do you have additional log when you ng build your project?

Comment: Yeah, the funny thing is there is no actual error in logs.

Comment: Keep on building the app . It will go

Answer (score 0):

It's a new error coming with Ivy. The error pretty much describes what's happening. You should try to fix the other errors that are thrown first and then this one will automatically disappear as well.

I was running into this as well as I usually just try to grab one error at a time and resolve it, but those you'll just need to leave until every other error is resolved and then they'll be gone as well.

Comment: That's pretty much the only error message I'm getting after an upgrade to 12 :)